# Passing values to default Django authentication form

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have very silly question:

How can I get value and assign it correctly to django variables `{{form.username}}` and `{{form.password}}`?

I have a bootstrap sign-in page and default django authentication views and forms for login :
`

```
  <form class="form-signin">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>

</div>`
```

If I put `value={{form.username}}` in `input tag` everything is working but I have to delete some text on start in input fields.

Django version - 1.10.6

Comment: Why would you want to set the password field to a predefined value?

Comment: I only want to know: how can I correct connect this login page with default django authentication form

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
{% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">
                {{ field.label }}
            </label>

            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <p class="text-danger">{{ error }}</p>
            {% endfor %}

            {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```